# Extract File Name from Txt File with dir

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, windows-7, cmd

I have a txt file that is used to store a directory that is used in a bat.

In the bat I need to set two variables. The full directory and then just the file name from the directory. I looked at the commands that relate to it and found this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true 
Which says I need the %~n1 command.

The Directory in the txt file is:
O:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Station 5 Log 20150324.CSV

So in my bat I tried to use this:

```
    set /p LogFile=<"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"
    set /p FileName=<%~n1"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"
```

That did not work the way I wanted. FileName is supposed to return the File Name at the end of the directory. "Station 5 Log 20150324.CSV"

So I ran a quick test to see if I could figure out what set up I needed to extract just the file name from the directory and ran this:

```
    Echo on
    Rem References the current week text file to find the name of the current week folder it should be saving to
    set /p LogFile=<"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"
    set /p FileName1=<%~n1"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"
    set /p FileName2=<"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"%~n1
    set /p FileName3=<"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"

    echo %LogFile%
    echo %FileName1%
    echo %FileName2%
    echo %~n1%FileName3%
    echo %FileName3%
    Pause
```

None of these options seemed to return just the file name and they actually left me asking more questions than I wanted so here I am. Any ideas on how I can get just the file name out of the txt file?

[windows 7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
set /p LogFile=<"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Macro Folder\LogFile.txt"
for %%a in ("%LogFile%") do set "FileName=%%~nxa"
```

The `for` command uses the variable to create a file reference, stored in `%%a`, and we just get the name and extension of the referenced file.